# Update Post Category if ACF Date has passed with Cron Job in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post, cron, categories, advanced-custom-fields

My case is that we have 2 Post Categories. 1. Upcoming Events and 2.Passed Events.

We create a post with ACF event_end_date which is an ACF Date picker. What we need to do is have a cron job that checks if the event_end_date has passed so it updates the Post Category from Upcoming Events to Passed Events. I just cant make it work. Here is the code if you guys got any input i would be thankful!

```php
/*  Scheduled Action Hook */
function check_event_end_date() {

  global $post;

  $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
     'category__in' => array(33), /*Upcoming Events Category ID*/
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  );

  $listings = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($listings as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

  $today = date( 'Ymd' );
  $expire = get_field( 'event_end_date', false, false );

        if ( $expire > $today ) :
            $post_categories="36"; /*Passed Events Category ID*/
            $append=false;
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $post_categories, $append );
        endif;  
    endforeach;

}

// Schedule Cron Job Event

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'event_end_date_cron_job' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( date( 'Ymd' ), 'daily', 'event_end_date_cron_job' );
}
add_action( 'event_end_date_cron_job', 'check_event_end_date' );
```

Comment: Can you describe better "doesn't work"? Does the cron runs? When you manually evoke you check_event_end_date() function does it trow any error?

Comment: The cron executes as it should, but it does not update the post category as it should. it does absolutely nothing.